# Why is it computationally more taxing to compute a circle using trigonometric equations over a system of ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, numerical-optimization

So lets say we were trying to compute a circle on a graph screen(like matlab), why would it be more convenient to compute this IVP instead rather than directly using trigonometric equations?

So my question is why abide from solving $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ point by point using some iteration scheme and rather solve this system of ODE's numerically with initial values $\begin{equation}\begin{cases}\dot{x}=-y,&& x(0)=r\\ \dot{y}=x, && y(0)=0\end{cases}\end{equation}$ by forward euler method, backward euler method, or trapezoidal method?

Comment: "Convenient" and "computationally more taxing" are two completely different criteria. But I suspect that the advantage of the ODE method is that you only need a rough approximation of the coordinates of the points along the circle in order to look like a circle on the computer screen, whereas the sin and cos functions will give you many digits of accuracy that you don't need. If the problem were instead to compute the coordinates of the points to the accuracy attainable by sin and cos, I suspect the ODE is at a disadvantage.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up a lot more

Comment: As a mix you can also take the trigonometric identities and compute $c_{n+1}=c_nc_1-s_ns_1$, $s_{n+1}=c_ns_1+s_nc_1$, so that only the initial angle needs the sine and cosine computed. Apply the usual symmetry expansion so that the computation of 1/8 of the circle is sufficient.